# Vista en SQL Server: Mostrar solo el máximo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema en SQL Server que no logro resolver. Estoy generando una vista que cruza varias tablas. Una de las tablas (órdenes de compra) tiene diferentes versiones, ya que el ERP genera una nueva versión por cada modificación que se le hace a la orden de compra. La vista que generé me trae toda la información que necesito, pero no logro que solo me muestre los datos de la mayor versión de la orden de compra a pesar que use MAX en cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Num (que es el número de versión). Les comparto el código y una imagen del resultado, donde se ve que el artículo modificado me trae como resultado la última versión y una previa. Muchas gracias!

```
SELECT        cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Nro AS [Numero de OC], MAX(cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Num) AS Versión, cmp35.ORD1.Ord1PrvCod AS [Código Proveedor], adm35.PRV.PrvNomOrd AS [Nombre Proveedor], cmp35.ORD2.PrdId AS [Código Artículo], 
                         ven35.PRD.PrdTxt AS [Nombre Artículo], cmp35.ORD2.Ord2Cnt AS Cantidad, cmp35.ORD3.Ord3FecEnt AS [Fecha Entrega], cmp35.ORD2.Ord2Cnt * cmp35.ORD2.Ord2Pcio AS [Valor s/IVA], 
                         cmp35.PGO1.TrP1PgoDsc AS [Condición de Pago], DATEADD(DAY, cmp35.PGO2.TrP2MasDia, cmp35.ORD3.Ord3FecEnt) AS [Fecha Vencimiento]
FROM            cmp35.PGO1 INNER JOIN
                         cmp35.PGO2 ON cmp35.PGO1.TrP1PgoId = cmp35.PGO2.TrP1PgoId INNER JOIN
                         adm35.PRV INNER JOIN
                         cmp35.ORD1 ON adm35.PRV.PrvId = cmp35.ORD1.Ord1PrvCod INNER JOIN
                         ven35.PRD INNER JOIN
                         cmp35.ORD2 ON ven35.PRD.PrdId = cmp35.ORD2.PrdId INNER JOIN
                         cmp35.ORD3 ON cmp35.ORD2.Ord1Suc = cmp35.ORD3.Ord1Suc AND cmp35.ORD2.Ord1Nro = cmp35.ORD3.Ord1Nro AND cmp35.ORD2.Ord1Num = cmp35.ORD3.Ord1Num AND 
                         cmp35.ORD2.Ord2Item = cmp35.ORD3.Ord2Item ON cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Nro = cmp35.ORD2.Ord1Nro AND cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Suc = cmp35.ORD2.Ord1Suc AND cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Num = cmp35.ORD2.Ord1Num ON 
                         cmp35.PGO1.TrP1PgoId = cmp35.ORD1.Ord1TrmPag
WHERE        (cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Suc = 1) AND (cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Abiert = 'S')
GROUP BY cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Nro, cmp35.ORD1.Ord1PrvCod, adm35.PRV.PrvNomOrd, cmp35.ORD2.PrdId, ven35.PRD.PrdTxt, cmp35.ORD2.Ord2Cnt, cmp35.ORD3.Ord3FecEnt, cmp35.ORD2.Ord2Cnt * cmp35.ORD2.Ord2Pcio, 
                         cmp35.PGO1.TrP1PgoDsc, DATEADD(DAY, cmp35.PGO2.TrP2MasDia, cmp35.ORD3.Ord3FecEnt)
```

[image: No debería traerme el resultado marcado en rojo ya que tiene dos versiones superiores]

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que `cmp35.ORD1.Ord1PrvCod` debe estar en el `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Es que si lo agrego como Expression me da error la consulta diciendo que debe estar en GROUP BY

Comment: A lo que iba era a que, ya que estás obteniendo el `MAX` de `cmp35.ORD1.Ord1PrvCod`, esta columna no tendría que aparecer en el `GROUP BY` (puede que esté equivocada, no manejo SQL Server).

Comment: Ah, entiendo lo que decís, pero en realidad estoy intentando obtener el MAX de cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Num, no de cmp35.ORD1.Ord1PrvCod.

Comment: Tenés toda la razón :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A priori parece que tienes un poco de lio en las relaciones de las tablas, porque si lo que quieres es la última versión del ord1, entonces solo tienes que recurrir a la tabla ord1 una vez. Y restringir la fila que quieres leer.

```
Create table ord1 (ord1 int, orditem int)
go
Insert into ord1 (ord1, orditem)
values
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)
go

Select *
       from ord1
       where ord1.orditem = (
              select Max(orditem)
                     from ord1 AS o
                     where o.ord1 = ord1.ord1
            );
```

[image: Result]

Eliminando lo que a priori, parece información redundante, en la vista podría ser algo tal que:

```
SELECT cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Nro AS [Numero de OC]
     , cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Num AS Versión
     , cmp35.ORD1.Ord1PrvCod AS [Código Proveedor]
     , adm35.PRV.PrvNomOrd AS [Nombre Proveedor]
     , cmp35.ORD1.PrdId AS [Código Artículo]
     , ven35.PRD.PrdTxt AS [Nombre Artículo]
     , cmp35.ORD1.Ord2Cnt AS Cantidad
     , cmp35.ORD1.Ord3FecEnt AS [Fecha Entrega]
     , cmp35.ORD1.Ord2Cnt * cmp35.ORD2.Ord2Pcio AS [Valor s/IVA]
     , cmp35.PGO1.TrP1PgoDsc AS [Condición de Pago]
     , DateAdd(DAY, cmp35.PGO2.TrP2MasDia, cmp35.ORD3.Ord3FecEnt) AS [Fecha Vencimiento]
       FROM cmp35.PGO1
            INNER JOIN cmp35.PGO2 ON cmp35.PGO1.TrP1PgoId = cmp35.PGO2.TrP1PgoId
            INNER JOIN cmp35.ORD1 ON cmp35.PGO1.TrP1PgoId = cmp35.ORD1.Ord1TrmPag
            INNER JOIN adm35.PRV ON adm35.PRV.PrvId = cmp35.ORD1.Ord1PrvCod
            INNER JOIN ven35.PRD ON ven35.PRD.PrdId = cmp35.ORD1.PrdId
            
       WHERE cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Suc = 1 AND cmp35.ORD1.Ord1Abiert = 'S'
        AND CMP35.ORD1.Ord1Num = (SELECT MAX(Ord1Num) FROM CMP35.ORD1 O WHERE O.Ord1Nro = CMP35.ORD1.ORD1Nro);
```

Existen varias maneras de alcanzar este resultado.

[Subquerys correlativas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/07/06/subquery-correlativa-y-otras-formas-de-conseguirlo/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder Javi fer2! Gracias a tu ayuda pude resolver el problema! El subquery no lo conocía y arregló el problema. Saludos!